# Using "ng-show" inside "ng-repeat",

Tags: angularjs

I'm developping web appliccation using AngularJS.
Applicattion show a list of items in a table.

This is the code which prints the table:

```
  <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in content.listaOperaciones>
            <td>{{ x.idOperacion }} </td>
            <td>{{ x.idGan }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.idEm}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.idGate}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.idRf }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.peso }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.duracion }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.timestampInicioOperacion | date:'dd-MM-yy HH:mm'}}</td>      
        </tr>
      </table>
```

This is how the [table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTUXV.png) once is printed in html.

I would like to implement multiple filters in each element in table by using some variables that can be accessed by user.

My idea is to filter each elements inside "`ng-repeat`" statement by using "`ng-show`" or "`ng-if`" statement.

This is the html code where user can modify variables:

```
<input ng-model="tiempoMinimo">
 <input ng-model="$ctrl.PesoMinimo">
 <input ng-model="$ctrl.PesoMaximo">
```

And this is how I'm modifying the table constructor:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in content.listaOperaciones | orderBy : $ctrl.orderProp | filter:$ctrl.Busc" ng-if="x.peso > $ctrl.PesoMinimo && x.peso < $ctrl.PesoMaximo">
  <div ng-show="x.duracion < $parent.tiempoMinimo">

    <td>{{ x.idOperacion }} </td>
    <td>{{ x.idGan }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.idEm}}</td>
    <td>{{ x.idGate}}</td>
    <td>{{ x.idRf }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.peso }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.duracion }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.timestampInicioOperacion | date:'dd-MM-yy HH:mm'}}</td>

</tr>
```

Filtering by using "`ng-if`" inside "`ng-repeat`" clausule is working.

Filtering by using "`ng show`" nested in "`ng-repeat`" loop is not working...

Since I want to use multiple filters (maybe 10 or 20) I would prefer using "`ng-show`" directive nested inside "`ng-repeat`" loop, so code would like easier to understand...

Here you have fiddle with source code working:
https://jsfiddle.net/DSG00/f94sjtty/

Thank you in advance.
Didac

Comment: Add a fiddle that reproduces the issue with some sample data.

Comment: `ng-show` will also work normally .. you may be missing something. Create some fiddle to replicate the issue.

Comment: Fiddle just added: https://jsfiddle.net/DSG00/f94sjtty/  Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle isn't working because you can't use `div` inside `tr`. Move your `ng-show` to the `tr` element where your `ng-repeat` is. Also change the condition like that `!$parent.tiempoMinimo || x.peso > $parent.tiempoMinimo` so when your input is empty it won't hide the whole table.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very Much.

So the only way if I want to apply multiple conditions in one ng-repeat in a table is to make something like that:

`'<tr ng-repeat="element in elements" ng show = condition1 && condition2 && condition3 &&condition4 && condition5>'`

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks additionnally for suggestion about how to solve hidding whole table when condition is empty... I was also struggling on that.

Comment: No need to clutter your html with expressions like that, if you want to apply multiple conditions you can declare a function which will obtain visibility for each element. Like `ng-show="isVisible(element)"`. Inside that function you can check as many conditions as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that way. It seems a much clever solution that one I was using (or trying to use). Best regards.